# javascript function preventdefault issue

Tags: javascript

I have the below javascript preventdefault issue.
I'm not very good at javascript, but this is what my code.
The `event.preventDefault` is not working, however if I replace to `alert("SOMETEXT")`, it is showing up the alert.

```
function changecartitemquantitykeydown(itemid,event) {
// Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 || 
     // Allow: Ctrl+A
    (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) || 
     // Allow: home, end, left, right
    (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
         // let it happen, don't do anything
         return;
}
else {
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if ((event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 )) || (this.value.length == 0 && event.keyCode == 48)) {
        event.preventDefault(); <===== This is not happening
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: How do you call that function? Looks like it should only have one parameter

Comment: Try to Use `return false` rather than `event.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this and it works.

```
function changecartitemquantitykeydown(event) {
// Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 || 
     // Allow: Ctrl+A
    (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) || 
     // Allow: home, end, left, right
    (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
         // let it happen, don't do anything
         return;
}
else {
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if ((event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 )) || (this.value.length == 0 && event.keyCode == 48)) {
        //cancelDefaultAction(event);           
        var evt = event ? event:window.event;
        if (evt.preventDefault) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
        evt.returnValue = false;
        return false;   
    }   
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in the fact that you have more than one argument in the function 'changecartitemquantitykeydown'. If this is the event callback function than the first argument should be the event. If you call preventDefault() on that, everything should be fine. Than you should figure out a way to get the itemid you want in that function.